# Maximum number of low weight vertices of cube

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbb F$ be a field. For a vector $v\in \mathbb F^n$, let $\|v\|_0$ denote the number of nonzero entries of $v$. Let $b\in \mathbb F^n$ and $A\in GL_n(\mathbb F)$ be an invertible matrix. What is the maximum possible value of 
$$
|\{x\in \{0,1\}^n: \|Ax+b\|_0\le k\}|?
$$
Note that for when $A$ is the identity matrix and $b=\mathbf 0$, this equals $\sum_{j=0}^k\binom nj$. However, this is NOT the best in general: for example, when $n=2,k=1$, we can achieve 4 by having $Ax+b$ be the cube $\{(0,\pm1),(\pm1,0)\}$.

An easy upper bound goes as follows: a $k$-dimensional hyperplane intersects $\{0,1\}^n$ in at most $\binom nk$ points, and $\{||x||_0\le k\}$ is a union of $\binom nk$ such hyperplanes. Thus the cardinality is upper-bounded by $\binom nk 2^k$. Can you do better?

(For the curious: this question came up when finding sufficient conditions for the exponential sum $\sum_{x\in \{0,1\}^n}\zeta_m^{f(x)}$ to be small when $f(x)$ is a quadratic polynomial modulo $m$. Squaring this and using Weyl differencing leads one to the above question with $A$ being a submatrix of the Hessian of $f$.)